# Проблема с аргументом

Tags: javascript

Есть функция. Как сделать, чтобы она имела такой смысл, возможность передачи аргумента

```
 function toltipImg() {
   var el =  document.getElementById("picture1")
   el = toltipUpImg(el);

 }
  function toltipUpImg(a){
     alert("a") //a == picture1
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function toltipImg() {
    $("#picture").each(function (index, value) {
        toltipUpimg($(this).attr('id'));
    });
}
```

Comment: Да нет, вы не поняли, я хочу, чтобы toltipUpImg(), как-то имел аргумент.

Comment: А на нативе никак нельзя?

Comment: можно, наверное так:
var len = getElementById('picture').length;
for (i=0;i<len;i++)
toltipimgUp('сюда ваши параметры');
PS: думаю правильнее будеть вместо id воспользоваться class-ом.